# C segmentation fault with very large array at specific indices

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a program that deals with very large arrays, and when I'm trying to populate the array with random values, it always segfaults at a specific index. On  Mac OSX 10.10 running XCode, it segfaults at index 1000448, and on GCC targeting LLVM version 6.1.0 it faults at 1001472.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define WIDTH 1000
#define HEIGHT 1000


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // set seed for rand()
    srand(2006);

    // 1. allocate host memory for matrices A and B
    unsigned int length = WIDTH * HEIGHT;
    unsigned int size = sizeof(int) * length;
    printf("%i", size);
    int* matrixA = (int*) malloc(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        matrixA[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    free(matrixA);
}
```

Why is this segfaulting? I checked the size allocated to matrixA, and it appears to be the correct size (4,000,000)

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc()`. Note also that the proper type for array-indexes and sizes is ... `size_t`.

Comment: Also note that `rand() % 10` will very likely not give a uniform distribution. But that should be no problem, as you will get the same values for every invocation anyway.

Comment: Any idea on why those particular sizes are the ones it chooses to fault at?

Comment: You are also mixing signed and unsigned types freely. Here is is mostly bad style, I do not see an actual problem., but it will bite you eventually in another program.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.   When #define'ing a numeric value, always wrap the value in parens to avoid text replacement problems.

Comment: always compile with all warnings enabled.  then fix the warnings.  (with gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')   Suggest eliminate two of the warnings by declaring main() as 'int main( void );

Comment: Try using more meaningful variable names; if `size` and `length` have different meanings then that is a clue that something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code

1. compiles cleanly
2. performs the appropriate error checking

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define WIDTH  (1000)
#define HEIGHT (1000)


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main( void )
{

    // set seed for rand()
    srand(2006);

    // 1. allocate host memory for matrices A and B
    unsigned int length = WIDTH * HEIGHT;
    unsigned int size = sizeof(int) * length;

    printf("%u\n", size);
    int* matrixA = NULL;
    if( NULL == (matrixA = malloc(size) ) )
    {// then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        matrixA[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    free(matrixA);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: The above code executes correctly.  The seg fault event was from writing past the end of the malloc'd memory.  Note the use of 'length' rather than 'size'  in the 'for' statement

Comment: "If someone could tell my why those particular values, though, it would be great? "   Since the code was writing past the end of the malloc'd memory, the code had undefined behaviour.  With undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I just realized what the problem was. I'm looping from 0 to size, instead of length. If someone could tell my why those particular values, though, it would be great

Comment: size is the total bytes that make up the matrix.  length is the number of elements in the matrix

Comment: I adapted code from a tutorial on OpenCL, but cut down all the non-pertinent parts